# Envio de formulário e array fora de form via post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Tenho o seguinte problema: Necessito enviar via `post` os dados de um formulário juntamente com os dados de uma tabela html ao qual monto um `array` em javascript.
Infelizmente, não faço a ideia de como proceder nesse caso.

Peço auxílio dos colegas neste desafio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens duas opções,

- enviar tudo via AJAX
- enviar os dados da tabela num input escondido

Se enviares por ajax podes usar o `.serialize()` do jQuery e enviar no ajax algo assim:

```
var fData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {form: fData, table: JSON.stringify(tDada)}, // onde tData é a array da tua tabela
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(msg)
   {
     $('.resposta').html(msg);
   }
});
```

se quiseres colocar esses dados da tabela dentro de um campo escondido:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tabela" id="dadosTabela" />
```

e depois injetas no valor do input os dados da tabela:

```
$('dadosTabela').val(JSON.stringify(fData));
```

Comment: Sergio, você salvou meu projeto! Rs. Eu já havia tentado colocar o array no campo tipo hidden. Mas tive dificuldades em aproveitar os dados depois do post, no lado do php. A sua solução de enviá-lo via JSON que tornou o processo funcional. Muito obrigado pelo apoio! Devo-lhe uma!

Answer (score 1):

**Eric**, temos duas opções:

1. **Serializar** os campos enviados dos campos utilizando o nome do campo como prefixo:
2. **Construir manualmente** a array com os campos enviados utilizando o nome do campo como prefixo:

**- MANEIRA "SERIALIZAR COM PREFIXO DE NOME"**

Sejam dois campos com prefixo "campo"

```
<input type="text" name="campoNome">
<input type="text" name="campoEmail">
```

Então, salvamos em uma variável o objeto contendo os dados dos campos:

```
var camposEnviados = $("input[name^='campo']").serialize();
```

**- MANEIRA "CONSTRUIR MANUALMENTE"**

Podemos construir a array manualmente (selecionando campo a campo o seu valor):

```
var camposEnviados = [];
camposEnviados[0] = $('campoNome').val();
camposEnviados[1] = $('campoEmail').val();;
```

**- ENVIANDO VIA AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {camposEnviados: camposEnviados},
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(msg)
   {
     $('.resposta').html(msg);
   }
});
```

Comment: Olá Felipe! Sua ideia e explicação me ajudaram muito na montagem final do processo. Acabei optando por lançar o array no value de input do tipo 'hidden' e na hora do submit. Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Grande abraço!

Comment: Eric, bom dia! Que bom que resolveu! Abraço